# get UITextField Tag in Custom Methods

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield

In my Project I have two `UITextFields`, one is used for Postal Code another one is used for Phone Number , so I used the `Keyboard` in `NumberPad`, Here I used the `UIToolbar` for both `UITextFields` for hide  values, but my problem is `TextField` is does not identify the correct `Tags` in custom Methods for hide the textfields. How to resolve this issue

[image]

and my code is

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad:)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad:)],
                       nil]; 
}


- (IBAction)cancelNumberPad:(UITextField*)textField {

NSLog(@"The user is typing in text field %d",textField.tag);


if (textField.tag==50) {
    [txtPostalCode resignFirstResponder];
    txtPostalCode.text=@"";
}
else
{
    [txtphoneno resignFirstResponder];

    txtphoneno.text = @"";
}

}

- (IBAction)doneWithNumberPad:(UITextField*)textField {


 NSLog(@"The user is typing in text field %d",textField.tag);


if (textField==txtPostalCode) {
    [txtPostalCode resignFirstResponder];

}
else
{
    [txtphoneno resignFirstResponder];


}
}


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if (textField.tag==50) {
    textField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}
else if

    (textField.tag==5) {
        textField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
    }
}
```

in my console report is

```
2014-05-03 14:06:23.614 why-Q[2000:60b] The user is typing in text field 0
```

how to get the correct tag in custom methods

Comment: How do you call method cancelNumberPad is EditingChanged Method of textfield

Comment: connect IBOutlet to the textField

Comment: see the screen shot bro, already connected and understand the question,

Comment: cancelNumberPad check the same textfield is passing or not. i think first textfield is pass

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837561/how-to-use-call-directory-extension-to-identify-a-incoming-call

Answer (score 1):

//yourviewcontroller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController    {
 int tag;
}
```

//yourviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    tag = 0;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField// return NO to disallow editing.
{    
    tag = textField.tag;        
    return YES;
}
- (IBAction)cancelNumberPad:(UITextField*)textField {        
    NSLog(@"The user is typing in text field %d",tag);        

}

- (IBAction)doneWithNumberPad:(UITextField*)textField {       

    NSLog(@"The user is typing in text field %d",tag);
}
```

Comment: ya fine bro, tanx a lot, I am not taken the tag from textfield delegate methods, now it working